# Few of the inputs refuse to update the db only if a banner is uploaded

Tags: php, html, twig, silex

For some reasons, the data is only updated if there is an upload of image happens. So if i only insert `path` or change the option `status` it does not update the data. But altogether with any of the `banner` uploaded and change `path` or `status` at the same time, then the `path` or `status` can be updated. But i dont think i included the `status` nor `path` in the if statement of the `banner` in the controller. Can someone please enlighten me? Thanks.

EDIT#1:

Extra info is that the form involves around 11 rows of data. Somehow the 1st row is not affected, which means that the `path` and the `status` input for the first row can be successfully updated without any `banner` uploaded. Should there be problems with the loops?

Controller.php

```
    function updateHeaderAction(Request $request){
        ini_set('max_file_uploads', 33);
        $data = $_FILES;
        $formData = $request->request->all();
        $name = array(
            1=>'right1',
            2=>'right2',
            3=>'right3',
            4=>'right4',
            5=>'right5',
            6=>'right6',
            7=>'right7',
            8=>'right8',
            9=>'right9',
            10=>'right10',
            11=>'logo',

        );
        end($data['banner']['name']);
        $key = key($data['banner']['name']);
        $a = array();
        for($i=0;$i<=$key;$i++){
            if(isset($data['banner']['name'][$i])){
                if(isset($data['banner']['name'][$i][0])){
                    $img = $this->forBannerUpload('banner','storage/header/en/',null,null,true,$i,0,true,$name[$i+1]);
                    $a[$i+1]['en'] = $img;
                }else{
                    $img = null;
                    $a[$i+1]['en'] = null;
                }
                if(isset($data['banner']['name'][$i][1])){
                    $img_zh = $this->forBannerUpload('banner','storage/header/hk/',null,null,true,$i,1,true,$name[$i+1]);
                    $a[$i+1]['hk'] = $img;
                }else{
                    $img_zh = null;
                    $a[$i+1]['hk'] = null;
                }
                if(isset($data['banner']['name'][$i][2])){
                    $img_cn = $this->forBannerUpload('banner','storage/header/cn/',null,null,true,$i,2,true,$name[$i+1]);
                    $a[$i+1]['cn'] = $img;
                }else{
                    $img_cn = null;
                    $a[$i+1]['cn'] = null;
                }
            }
                $status = $formData['status'][$i];
                $path = $formData['path'][$i];
                $query = new HeaderModule($this->app);
                $query->updateHeader($i+1,$img,$img_zh,$img_cn,$status,$path);
//            $a[] = $name[]
//            $a[$i] = $name[$id[$i]];
//            $img = $this->uploadImageAction('banner','storage/page_banner/',null,null,true,$id[$i],true,$name[$id[$i]]);
//            $this->app['query']->updateBanner($id[$i],$img);
        }
//
//        ob_start();
//        var_dump($a);
//        return ob_get_clean();
        return true;
    }
```

HTML

```
{% for key,item in data %}
<tr>
    <td class="hidden-xs-portrait">
        <div>
            <div class="ea_flag"></div>
            {{ item.name }}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="hidden-xs-portrait">
        {% if item.header_img_src is not null and item.header_img_src is not empty %}
            <div>
                <div class="es_flag" style="top: 1px;"></div>
                <div>EN:</div>
                <img src="{{ app.request.baseUrl }}/{{ item.header_img_src }}" width="150" />
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if item.header_img_src_zh is not null and item.header_img_src_zh is not empty %}
            <div>
                <div class="hs_flag" style="top: 1px;"></div>
                <div>HK:</div>
                <img src="{{ app.request.baseUrl }}/{{ item.header_img_src_zh }}" width="150" />
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if item.header_img_src_cn is not null and item.header_img_src_cn is not empty %}
            <div>
                <div class="cs_flag" style="top: 1px;"></div>
                <div>CN:</div>
                <img src="{{ app.request.baseUrl }}/{{ item.header_img_src_cn }}" width="150" />
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </td>
    <td>
        {#<input type="file" class="image-upload" name="banner[1]" >#}
        <div class="ea_flag"></div>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" name="banner[{{key}}][0]">
        <div class="ha_flag"></div>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" name="banner[{{key}}][1]">
        <div class="ca_flag"></div>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" name="banner[{{key}}][2]">
        <label for="programme-status" class="control-label">Programme Status:</label>
        <select required="required" name="status[{{key}}]" class="form-control programme-status header-status">
            {% if item.status == 0 %}
            <option value="0" selected>Hidden</option>
            <option value="1">Show</option>
            {% else %}
            <option value="0">Hidden</option>
            <option value="1" selected>Show</option>
            {% endif %}
        </select>

        <div class="en_flag"></div><label style="position: relative; margin-left:25px;" for="programme-link-description" class="control-label ">Hyperlink:</label>
        <div class="controls form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control header-path" name="path[{{key}}]" value="{{item.path}}">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Module.php

```
function updateHeader($id,$img,$img_zh,$img_cn,$status,$path){
    if($img!=null){
        $sql['header_img_src'] = $img;
    }
    if($img_zh!=null){
        $sql['header_img_src_zh'] = $img_zh;
    }
    if($img_cn!=null){
        $sql['header_img_src_cn'] = $img_cn;
    }
    $sql['path'] = $path;
    $sql['status'] = $status;
    return $this->app['db']->update('header',$sql, array('id' => (int)$id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add attribute `accept=` in `<input>` tag.
More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept

Comment: but the file itself can be successfully updated without error. It is the `path` and the `status` input that cannot go through